# React Native: How to animate opacity of ScrollView/ListView children as they enter/leave the viewport?

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native

How is this done in React Native? I've tried using touchable opacity, but it doesn't work. And, there doesn't seem to be documentation about how to do this in ScrollView.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Animated.

Check the first example in the docs below.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a custom Item component that runs the animation on componentDidMount. For example, if you have a list of users, each item on the list should be a `UserItem` component.

```
class UserItem extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.startAnimation()
  }

  startAnimation() {
    Animated.timing(this.animatedValue, {
       toValue  : 1,
       duration : 500,
    }).start()
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <Animated.View
         style={[someStyles, { opacity: this.animatedValue }]}
       >
         <AnyThingYouNeedHere />    
       </Animated.View>
    );
  }
}
```

Then in your list you just need to use `UserItem`. You might want to add some delay for each item or something else.

Here's a great tutorial that shows you how to add animations when adding/removing items.

http://moduscreate.com/react-native-dynamic-animated-lists/

Good luck!

Comment: Will try this. Thank you.